# C# - System Diagnostics - File Log Getting all output from console

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics

I have the following code to configure my System Diagnostics, this configuration is to Write only Errors when it hits the `Trace.Error`.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="1">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textLogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="Logs\Trace.log"  />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

The problem here is that it is writing everything of the console output to the Log file, which is not what I want, since I only want the `Errors`.
I don't know if this will only happen in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set TraceLevel into `system.diagnostic` with `value="4"` means which means Error Level.

```
  <switches>  
      <add name="mySwitch" value="4" />  
   </switches>
```